# Command for creating a directory and navigating into it directly?

Tags: directory, cd-command, mkdir

Quite often I need to perform this two commands:

```
mkdir abc
cd abc
```

I am curious whether there is a simple command (**or an alias that I can create and use**) to do it in one go, like

```
user@GROUP:~$ mdcd abc
user@GROUP:~/abc$
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
mdcd() {
    mkdir "$@" && cd "$@"
}
```

Logout and login again or start a new shell to make the change.

Comment: Heh, exactly what I've been using for the past few years! No need to restart the shell though: just use `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @deltab yes, but sourcing again can cause problem if some codes in `.bashrc` wasn't expected to be loaded twice. Just start a new shell is safer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also simply do the following:

```
mkdir <name>; cd $_
```